# Ruby Application with metaprogramming - How to get bytecode or binary or something which can be ported

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a ruby application with meta programming. Application job is to read multiple input files (which can have user defined functions and data). Application parses and then executes functions after parsing.
I am wondering, is there a way I can get an executable or bytecode or something after parsing is done. So I can export this exe/bytecode and run "execute" part of processing on a different machine(same configuration).

Env detail:
Ruby 2.7.2
OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.7)

Comment: What programming language are the "user defined functions and data" written in? Are they also in Ruby? (you have a ruby application that runs other ruby applications?)

Comment: Have a look here. Looks like it has not been updated in a while, but perhaps still worth to check out. https://github.com/loureirorg/rb2exe

Comment: Not really. Unlike Python, which creates .pyc files, there's no on-disk compilation of the Ruby VM byte code. What problem are you actually trying to solve with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Because of how dynamic Ruby is, the only way to meaningfully know that you have valid code is to run it. The C API *almost* supports this through the `ruby_exec_node` function, but last I checked there is not much support for this style of running Ruby. Even if that was more convenient to use, I don't know how much skipping the parsing step would really save you.

Most of the Ruby VMs that produce bytecode are JIT-style, meaning they only generate byte code *after* they have executed the code once via the VM. This works best for Ruby because again it is so dynamic that it's hard to say what it is going to do without actually running it.